# Bullet3: Issue with applying force once an object is at rest

Tags: c++, physics, bullet-physics

I just started using bullet and I'm having an issue where once my rigid body is at reset at the floor it won't move when I apply a force to it.

I have created a small demo to show this using the hello world example provided [here](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Hello_World).

```
for(int i = 0; i<30000; i++) // Give it a lot of time to hit the ground
{
    dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1 / 60.f, 10);
}

btVector3 froce(0.0, 2000.0, 0.0); 
fallRigidBody->applyCentralForce(froce);// Apply a force on the Y axis 

for(int i = 0; i<300; i++) {
    dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1 / 60.f, 10);

    btTransform trans;
    fallRigidBody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(trans);

    std::cout << "Frame # : " << i
        << "\t: X: " << trans.getOrigin().getX()
        << "\t, Y: " << trans.getOrigin().getY()
        << "\t, Z: " << trans.getOrigin().getZ()
        << "\n";
}
```

The result I get out of this is:

```
Frame # : 0     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 1     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 2     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 3     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 4     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 5     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 6     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 7     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 8     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 9     : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 10    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 11    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 12    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 13    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 14    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 15    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 16    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 17    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 18    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
Frame # : 19    : X: 0.00       , Y: 1.00       , Z: 0.00
```

As you can see, the object never moved.

Now if I lower the first loop from `30000` to `300` then it will move just as I expect

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full code if anyone wants to test it out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <btBulletDynamicsCommon.h>

int main(void)
{

    btBroadphaseInterface* broadphase = new btDbvtBroadphase();

    btDefaultCollisionConfiguration* collisionConfiguration = new btDefaultCollisionConfiguration();
    btCollisionDispatcher* dispatcher = new btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration);

    btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver* solver = new btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver;

    btDiscreteDynamicsWorld* dynamicsWorld = new btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, broadphase, solver, collisionConfiguration);

    dynamicsWorld->setGravity(btVector3(0, -10, 0));


    btCollisionShape* groundShape = new btStaticPlaneShape(btVector3(0, 1, 0), 1);

    btCollisionShape* fallShape = new btSphereShape(1);


    btDefaultMotionState* groundMotionState = new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, -1, 0)));
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo
        groundRigidBodyCI(0, groundMotionState, groundShape, btVector3(0, 0, 0));
    btRigidBody* groundRigidBody = new btRigidBody(groundRigidBodyCI);
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(groundRigidBody);


    btDefaultMotionState* fallMotionState =
        new btDefaultMotionState(btTransform(btQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1), btVector3(0, 50, 0)));
    btScalar mass = 1;
    btVector3 fallInertia(0, 0, 0);
    fallShape->calculateLocalInertia(mass, fallInertia);
    btRigidBody::btRigidBodyConstructionInfo fallRigidBodyCI(mass, fallMotionState, fallShape, fallInertia);
    btRigidBody* fallRigidBody = new btRigidBody(fallRigidBodyCI);
    dynamicsWorld->addRigidBody(fallRigidBody);

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);

    for(int i = 0; i<300; i++) // Give it a lot of time to follow to the ground
    {
        dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1 / 60.f, 10);
    }

    btVector3 froce(0.0, 2000.0, 0.0); 
    fallRigidBody->applyCentralForce(froce);// Apply a force on the Y axis 

    for(int i = 0; i<50; i++) {
        dynamicsWorld->stepSimulation(1 / 60.f, 10);

        btTransform trans;
        fallRigidBody->getMotionState()->getWorldTransform(trans);

        std::cout << "Frame # : " << i
            << "\t: X: " << trans.getOrigin().getX()
            << "\t, Y: " << trans.getOrigin().getY()
            << "\t, Z: " << trans.getOrigin().getZ()
            << "\n";
    }

    dynamicsWorld->removeRigidBody(fallRigidBody);
    delete fallRigidBody->getMotionState();
    delete fallRigidBody;

    dynamicsWorld->removeRigidBody(groundRigidBody);
    delete groundRigidBody->getMotionState();
    delete groundRigidBody;


    delete fallShape;

    delete groundShape;


    delete dynamicsWorld;
    delete solver;
    delete collisionConfiguration;
    delete dispatcher;
    delete broadphase;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked in this issue, and it seems that you have to call the `activate` function on the `rigidbody` after applying the force. [This](http://bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Activation) article does say that you `generally do not have to` but it seems that you must do it manually once it is has gone to sleep.

Comment: This looks about right. Usually with sleeping you need to set an awake flag for the simulation to include a sleeping body back into the island simulating.

Comment: @RandyGaul You would think that internally, when you add a force then the flag should be set automatically with it. I can't imagine a reason why you wouldn't want the library to do that.

Comment: Yeah you'd think so. My own implementation does this, and I thing Box2D does too. Usually it won't even matter in terms of cache hits as the memory for applying a force is next to the bitmask for the sleeping flag...